# How to load a directive into a module after instantiating using requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-amd

To describe my hurdle, A little back story. I was injecting all the requirejs path files(directives basically) which contains any directive to my main module in the app.js, which was working perfect. Its somewhat like

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'angular-resource', 'angularTranslate', 'angularTranslateLoaderStaticFiles', 'bootstrap', 'angular-idle', 'loadingMaskDirective', 'multiselectDirective', 'treeview.directive', 'tabs', 'checklist.directive'], function(angularAMD) { 
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "ngTable", "myApp.directives", 'ui.bootstrap', 'flow']);
app.config(....){
/**some route provider**/
}...
angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
return app;
```

I have defined all directives and also injected them to main module. But I want to define some **directive in their indivisual controller** to reduce initial load. There has to be some method. Right !!

And code in my directive js files looks like..

```
define(['angular'], function() {
angular.module('myApp').directive('SomeDirective',
        ['$parse', '$compile', '$rootScope', '$filter', function($parse, $compile, $rootScope, $filter) {
.........
```

So, when I try to define the same in page controller not in app.js, It doesn't work. However I am amazed that the **factory function in this case works but not directive**.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use app to create the directive?

```
define(['app'], function(app) {
app.directive('SomeDirective',
        ['$parse', '$compile', '$rootScope', '$filter', function($parse, $compile, $rootScope, $filter) {
.........
```

An alternative provided by `angularAMD` is:

```
define(['angularAMD'], function(angularAMD) {
angularAMD.directive('SomeDirective',
        ['$parse', '$compile', '$rootScope', '$filter', function($parse, $compile, $rootScope, $filter) {
.........
```

The benefit of 2nd approach is to allow loading of directive before loading of your `app.js`.  See [Loading Application Wide Module](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD#loading-application-wide-module) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks @marcoseu, the first method isn't working. Tried it, though second one provides solution to my problem. So,here is angularAMD registers the directive to my main module  and according to **angularAMD.<<recipe>>**, can I use providers like factory,service,controller etc. in recipe section ? Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: We can use app.register.directive to make the first solution working. I think register exposes the providers for use.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal make sure to check the version of angularAMD that you are using.  The `app.register.<<recipe>>` has been deprecated in favour of the ``app.<<recipe>>`.